# I recently update my blog and after that some of my java-script gadgets are not working in my blogspot/blogger website

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I recently update my blog and after that some of my java-script gadgets are not working. How to get it back. I forget about what I had changed in my blog?

There is gadgets on header which display the post title of my recent blog. ON top left side there is a gadgets which shows rejects post and features post. Now these two gadgets are not working.

My blog address is [http://techzp.blogspot.in/.](http://techzp.blogspot.in/)

[image: image depicting issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are calling jquery library multiple time and in multiple version, and when the browser got error for jquery don't elaborate successive code

Try linking jquery only one time in the HEAD tag